# Interface that requires attribute to be implemented

Tags: c#, generics, interface

Is there a way to create interface with attribute which has to be used by the class that implements interface?

I.e. if class Foo implements interface IFoo, and IFoo is defined to must have ObserveMeAttribute, then Foo must have ObserveMe defined on it in order to implement IFoo.

Edit:

Attribute is called EntityTypeAttribute and is used to specify entity type for the view model, with usage:

```
[EntityType(typeof(User))]
public class UserViewModel
{
...
}
```

Attribute is used in an extension method AddModel(T TModel) where attribute is read from TModel, and it's property Type entityType is used to create entity stub object.

Comment: Admittedly, I've not done much with Interfaces since college, but I thought if a class implemented an Interface, it had to implement everything in that interface?  That's what I gather from [Interfaces (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173156.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer is "no".  If every object *must* have this value to implement IFoo why don't you make it part of the IFoo interface?

Attributes are primarily a mechanism for finding additional declarative information about a class/method/parameter at **run-time** by using reflection.

Comment: They are also introduced to abstract repetitive logic away from the classes which is what I'm trying to do. I'm also not fond of introducing additional properties to my model classes that are not part of the object definition.

Comment: You are probably stuck with having to check for the presence of this attribute at run-time (or in a custom build step) then.  Repetitive logic to deal with something that has an Ixxx interface on it could be placed in an Extension method.  An example of your attribute and usage might help.

Comment: I've added description of attribute. Basically I want to ensure that my generic view model has to be decorated with EntityTypeAttribute rather than creating error handling.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that. But you can solve your problem by making your ViewModel class generic with a Model class generic argument:

```
public abstract class Model
{
...
}

public abstract class ViewModel<TModel> where TModel : Model
{
...
}
```

and implement your repetitive logic in this abstract classes for each Model and ViewModel. Then you will have:

```
public class User : Model
{
...
}

public class UserViewModel : ViewModel<User>
{
...
}
```